# Android Device wont connect

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, galaxy-tab

I am trying to run my android app on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 device. The tablet connects to the computer ok, but isnt showing up on android studios. Ive been searching for about an hour trying to fix it but nothing seems to work, any help is massively appreciated thanks

Comment: Try to kill adb process n than restart it again..

Comment: Write this command in cmd "kill adb" , or go to task manager and find adb.exe process and click on End task if u r using Windows...

Comment: I thought u know about debugging mode, u have to enable debugging mode to run app in real devices..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable developer settings by clicking on "Build number" in "About phone" tab seven times. Then head to developer settings which you just enabled and enable "USB debugging"

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug mode on the device.

Comment: Google is your friend https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm

Comment: Go to this link to enable debugging mode in Samsung device -  http://www.mobisynapse.com/forum/topic/how-to-enable-debugging-mode-on-samsung-android-phone